# issue with mysql php

Tags: php, mysql, database

how come 1 works and 2 does not????

1

```
$temp = mysql_query("SHOW DATABASES LIKE "."'"."cwed"."'",$con);
$check = mysql_num_rows($temp)>0;
```

2

```
  $tmp = mysql_real_escape_string('SHOW DATABASES LIKE "cwed"');
  $temp = mysql_query($tmp,$con); 
  $check = mysql_num_rows($temp)>0;
```

the problem is while i check for mysql_num_rows($temp)  i get the error

> Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:*******\ in line 21.

So i figured out that my query returns a bool instead of resource this will happen in this case $temp is bool instead of resource with value 0. When i checked in my terminal it said the set is 0. So how come in this case i am getting bool instead of 0

Comment: Check error using `mysql_query($tmp,$con) or die(mysql_error());`

Comment: i dont know why you are using the mysql_real_escape_string here ? security through obscurity is not a good idea

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://www.brightmeup.info/article.php?a_id=2).

Comment: thank you will have a look into it

Answer (score 5):

The problem is the `mysql_escape_string` call in your second example  it's munging up your quotes.  Echo out tmp and you will see that it's transforming

```
SHOW DATABASES LIKE "cwed"
```

to

```
SHOW DATABASES LIKE \"cwed\"
```

Comment: you are going fast   43 days and 7.6k rep ... awesome +1

Comment: I'm off my meds and the OCD is kicking in :)

Comment: i tot it should escape it SHOW DATABASES LIKE \"cwed\" so tat msq_query can unescape it later while usage. i knoew \ will added

Comment: @VISHWAASMANJUNATH could you rephrase it ?  your message is incomprehensible

Comment: @NullPoiиteя Orangepill will break record of **Jon Skeet**. :P

Comment: @NullPoiиteя I think that may be mathmatically impossible.

Comment: It's important to note here you escape things put *into* your query string, but you do not escape the *entire* query string. Using [placeholder values](http://bobby-tables.com/php) would make this a lot easier.

Comment: NULLpointer - i meant i knew \ will  be added when using mysql_real_escape_String() and i thought that was how it was supposed to be>

Answer (score 0):

`mysql_real_escape_string()` calls MySQL's library function mysql_real_escape_string, which prepends backslashes to the following characters: `\x00`, `\n`, `\r`, `\`, `'`, `"` and `\x1a`. its from the manual.
that's the reason your code is not working .

your code should be :-

```
$query = 'SHOW DATABASES LIKE "cwed"';
$temp = mysql_query($query,$con); 
$check = mysql_num_rows($temp)>0;
```

Answer (score -1):

remove `mysql_real_escape_string`

```
$tmp = mysql_real_escape_string('SHOW DATABASES LIKE "cwed"');
var_dump($tmp);
exit();

//string(28) "SHOW DATABASES LIKE \"cwed\""
```

Comment: please explain why it will work ... since op is telling that when he is not using the MRES then its working